# OPNSense VGA MBR USB

Tags: mbr, efi, pfsense

I want to install OPNSense on my HP DL360 G6 but it only boots USB drives that use MBR partition scheme, not EFI.  The VGA img file is EFI, so it doesn't recognize it and doesn't boot.  And when I try to make a bootable USB using Rufus with the DVD ISO of OPNSense, it says it isn't a bootable ISO file.

The Nano image is MBR, but you can't install that to the hard drive.

How can I make an MBR bootable USB to install OPNSense to the HDD?

Comment: In their `amd64` images *UEFI boot is supported as well* meaning "additionally" not instead of (BIOS boot). Almost all 64-bit OpenBSD or Linux based distro nowadays can boot in BIOS or UEFI modes. If you want to have BIOS only, choose the 32-bit version.  For OPNsense 32 or 64-bit probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia but the machine was going to have more than 4GB of RAM.  It's just that the HP doesn't recognize it as a boot drive when I make the USB with `dd` and the VGA image.

Comment: You may need to update the BIOS. There are several discussions in forums and Reddit mentioning problems about USB boot. If nothing helps, try burning a DVD.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia After updating my BIOS, it still doesn't let me boot from the USB.  And the issue with the DVD install is that it doesn't have a DVD slot.